# d3 reads only first property of csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

**Desired result**

The test.csv needs to be fully accessed for data reading.

**Current State**

I have moved some of the values around within the file for different test cases. It appears that the first entry of each row, regardless of type, is the only one that can be returned. At no point have I got any console errors.

**The CSV**

```
started, numb, eggs, waffles, name, cost
False, 34, "over easy", True, elle, 22
True, 24, "scrambled", False, belle, 22
False, 10, "fortunate", False, jake, 20
```

Using the line 3 `console.log(data)` reveals that the objects have been successfully loaded with the appropriate key/values.

```
[1]Object
" cost": " 22"
" eggs": " "scrambled""
" name": " belle"
" waffles": " False"
numb: "24"
```

(d3 added quotes around everything, looks like JSON. Have they been cast as string, or are quotes just delimiters?)

**d3.js**

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    var canv = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("height", 500)
                .attr("width", 500)

    canv.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("height", 15)
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.numb})
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 50 + i * 20})
            .attr("fill", "orange")

    canv.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 50 + i * 20})
            .text( function(d) {return d.started;})
    });
```

In this case, the `started` property prints on screen but the rectangles have width 0.

When `numb` is the first entry for each row, the rects have appropriate widths, but no other attributes print.

**What is the error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that your `csv` file has spaces after each comma.  This is a mal-formed file, in a true `csv` file **commas are the delimiter** NOT comma-space.

Second problem is that `d3` won't autoconvert your data to specific types.  Usually you provide a [row conversion function](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv) to do convert data to proper formats.  Yours might look like this:

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(d) {

  return {
    started: d.started === 'True',
    numb: +d.numb,
    eggs: d.eggs,
    waffles: d.waffles === 'True',
    name: d.name,
    cost: +d.cost
  };

}, function(data) {

  console.log(data); 

  ...
```

[Fixing these problems up and your visualization start to take shape](http://plnkr.co/edit/94v69FbyM4iGhpRVdKdV?p=preview)

Comment: I incorrectly assumed whitespace was ignored. The exception must be `\n`, which would serve as an identifier for a new row. Thanks for the Plunker.

Comment: the line `started: d.started === 'True'` is interesting. The values of started are converted to Boolean, which is good. The default value would be False though, since strings are not equal to Booleans, right? The === in this case does not assign `started: value` to True, it converts it from string to Boolean by === being False, casting that key to Boolean.

Comment: @Naltroc, not sure I understand your question, `d.started === 'True'` is a string to string comparison: `'True' === 'True'` (which is `true`) or `'False'==='True'` (which is `false`).

Comment: okay. `'True'` is in quotes, which I did not acknowledge. Therefore it is a string to string comparison which continues to a comparison of the string contents, which returns True for matches and False otherwise, assigning the attribute that return value. Gotchya.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was reading the csv using function "then".

```
d3.csv("../../data/TA_CH_3.csv").then(function (data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

I also have to mention I didn't have the problem of comma and space as it was described above. But it was still reading only one row and this function fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For custom delimiters you can use:

```js
d3.dsv(', ')("your_file.csv", function(error, data){
   ...
}
```

To install:

`npm install d3-dsv`